# body += chunk will reallocate the entire response string every time a chunk arrives?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was reading this article => http://mgutz.com/2010/10/01/check_gmail_with_node_js.html.

Below in the comments Shomrom says:

> body += chunk will reallocate the
>   entire response string every time a
>   chunk arrives. I believe it would be
>   much better to append each chunk to an
>   array and do a .join() when you have
>   all you need.

**Does 
body += chunk really reallocate the entire response string every time a chunk arrives?** If so, what is the best way to improve this snippet that we can print `body` as cheap possible?

It contains the following snippet:

```
var http = require('http');

var user = 'user@gmail.com';
var password = 'password';
var auth = new Buffer(user + ':' + password).toString('base64');

var google = http.createClient(443, 'mail.google.com', true);
var request = google.request('GET', '/mail/feed/atom/', {
    'Host': 'mail.google.com', 
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + auth 
});

request.addListener('response', function(res) {
    var body = '';    
    res.addListener('data', function(chunk) { 
        body += chunk;
    });
    res.addListener('end', function() { 
        console.log(body); 
    });
});

request.end();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily every time, but in general it may do so quite often (say half the time, depending on the length of your strings and the implementation of JavaScript). Using an array and join is a good recommendation:

```
var bodyBuilder = [];
res.addListener('data', function(chunk) {
    bodyBuilder.push(chunk);
});
```

When you're done, join with

```
var body = bodyBuilder.join('');
```

The reason for this is that strings are usually stored as contiguous arrays of characters. When extra characters are appended, the array may have to be moved in memory if there's not enough free space past the end of the string to store the extra stuff. An implementation may reserve some extra space, but how much is out of your control.

Comment: This is not true if the JavaScript implementation uses the amazing rope data structure for strings, but nobody uses ropes.

Comment: Very good. I think that even using a Buffer could be more efficient allthough you don't know the size prehand I guess. Or maybe you could extract it from the first header? content-length?

Comment: I'd rather go with a buffer based approach and reallocate that when needed, which will be way faster than joining the array, also until the hacks land that let Node.js grab into V8 land to get direct string pointers, writing huge strings out to something is VERY slow.